# Continuity of second order partials at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, partial-derivative

I have the following function $$f(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \frac{x^4 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2} & ;(x,y) \neq (0,0), \\ 0 & ;(x,y) = (0,0). \end{array} \right.$$ I have shown that the second order partials exist at $(0,0)$ by making use of their respective limit definitions. Now, I have also explicitly computed the second order partials at $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and have shown that since $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$, this would mean they are continuous at all points including $(0,0)$; this was from a theorem proved in class.

My question is, how do we show that $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ are continuous at $(0,0)$? Their formulas are: $$f_{xx} = \frac{2(x^6 + 3x^4y^2 + 9x^2y^4 - y^6)}{(x^2 + y^2)^3} \\ f_{yy} = \frac{2(y^6 + 3y^4x^2 + 9y^2x^4 -x^6)}{(x^2 + y^2)^3}$$

Comment: $f_{yy}$ does not appear to have a limit at $(0,0)$. Note that the functions
$$
f_{yy}(t,t) = \frac{2 \cdot (1 + 3 + 9 - 1) t^6}{(2t^2)^3} = 3, \quad
f_{yy}(t,2t) = \frac{2 \cdot (2^6 + 3\cdot 2^4 + 9 \cdot 2^2 - 1) \cdot t^6}{(3t^2)^3} = \frac{98}9
$$
have distinct limits as $t \to 0$.

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing that out; I hadn't considered doing it that way at all! Also, I showed that $$f_{yy} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f_y(0,h) - f_y(0,0)}{h} = 2$$ Is this viable for showing existence at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Yes, that is a correct way to show that $f_{yy}$ exists at $(0,0)$.